# How to prevent a click event on a button from triggering by using another button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling

I have a button with id "myButton" when clicked it should increase the count in span with id "clickCount"   by 1 every time, the other button has an id "deactivate", when clicked it should no longer allow the increase in count even if the button with id "myButton" is clicked, I can manage upto the increase in count, but don't know how to stop the count from increasing without disabling the first button.

HTML

```
<button id="myButton">Click me!</button>
<p>You clicked on the button <span id="clickCount">0</span> times</p>
<button id="deactivate">Désactivate counting</button>
```

Javascript

```
let myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
let newCount = document.getElementById('clickCount');
let deact = document.getElementById('deactivate');
let count = 0;
 myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
 count++;
 newCount.innerText = count;
});
```

Comment: you can add an event listener in the button that controls if the counter button is disabled or not.

Comment: Did you consider to deactivate `myButton` on click of `deactivate`?

Comment: I have to do it without disabling the "myButton" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the event listener from `#myButton` when the other button is clicked

```js
let myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
let newCount = document.getElementById('clickCount');
let deact = document.getElementById('deactivate');
let count = 0;
function handler() {
  count++;
  newCount.innerText = count;
}

myButton.addEventListener('click', handler);
deact.addEventListener('click', () => myButton.removeEventListener('click', handler));
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Click me!</button>
<p>You clicked on the button <span id="clickCount">0</span> times</p>
<button id="deactivate">Désactivate counting</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `boolean` that changes to true on deactivation and allows increment when it is false:

```js
let myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
let newCount = document.getElementById('clickCount');
let deact = document.getElementById('deactivate');
let count = 0;
let deactivated = false;
deact.addEventListener("click", function(){
     deactivated = true;
});
myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
     if(!deactivated){
          count++;
          newCount.innerText = count;
     }
});
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Click me!</button>
<p>You clicked on the button <span id="clickCount">0</span> times</p>
<button id="deactivate">Désactivate counting</button>
```